# Return all rows of a data frame with a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame with multiple columns, one of which (called: drift.N) is a series of TRUE's and FALSES's. How would I go about separating the "TRUE" rows from the "FALSE" rows or asking R to tell me which rows    drift.N=="TRUE" ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a data.frame called `df`:

```
df[df$column_name,]
```

gets you the subset of the data.frame where `column_name` equals `TRUE`. To get the `FALSE` subset:

```
df[!df$column_name,]
```

(spot the exclamation mark !), where ! is `NOT`. To get the indices where `column_name` is `TRUE`:

```
which(df$column_name)
which(!df$column_name)
```

Finally, I recommend you go online and download some basic R tutorials and work through them. This questions, and many other basics, will be treated in them. See e.g.:

- http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/
- http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html

Answer (score 2):

It is really quite easy because `R` can use logical indexing.  So if `drift.N` already contains TRUE/FALSE, then simply:

```
yourdata[yourdata[, "drift.N"], ]
```

should work.  Basically, pass the column vector `yourdata[, "drift.N"]` as the row subset you want from your whole data frame, `yourdata`.  The rows where `drift.N == TRUE` will be returned.